# Pandas Plot, how to control the bar width and the gaps

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart

Hope this is an easy question -- how to control the bar width and the gaps when plotting with Pandas?

[Full code is here](https://gist.github.com/suntong/8c4929a2ee82b977dfc0/511730537e8d0b56d2ef540f66c2ccbab4375b38), reposted below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'person':[x*3 for x in list('ABCDEF')],
        'score1':np.random.randn(6),
        'score2':np.random.randn(6),
        'score3':np.random.randn(6),
        'score4':np.random.randn(6),
        'score5':np.random.randn(6)
                   })
print(df)
ax = df.set_index(['person']).plot(kind='barh')
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

[image]

The result bar width is too thin and the gaps is too wide, how can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set the `width` of the bars:

```
ax = df.set_index(['person']).plot(kind='barh', width=1.0)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Make them thinner again:

```
ax = df.set_index(['person']).plot(kind='barh', width=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: What about removing the space between the bars and still maintaining the width of the bar

Comment: Than you wold have white space either at the top or the bottom. Does not add anything, I guess.